# Web app fails over to partner in mirror very slowly

Tags: sql-server, mirror

I have 3 SQL servers in a mirror, one acting as witness with a DB mirrored with high safety. When I fail over from principal to mirror, the app goes down and sometimes comes back up after 2 refreshes, sometimes 5 minutes. It keeps trying to connect to the principal (I can see the denied attempts in the log for the user). These are not named instances.

I've tried with and without including "Failover Partner" in the connection string (shouldn't need it with a witness I think). And I am using DNS names for the principal and mirror, matching what it is in "mirroring_partner_instance". I've tried adding a timeout to the connection string and specifying on TCPIP. I've also turned on SQL browser. Just things I have tried based on other posts.

I remember mirror fail overs being very fast, almost instant. Am I just being too impatient? Is there a way to speed up the retry?

Comment: Am I reading your setup correctly in that you're using a DNS entry to point to what is the current active partner in the mirroring topology? If so, what is the TTL on the entry?

Comment: No, I'm using a DNS entry for the primary and mirror server. Including both in the connection string (Failover Partner). I have tried just the IP address as well.